# eigenConfig.cmake not found (ROS Indigo)

Tags: eigen, cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile a ros node that uses the eigen library. I am working on Indigo, but I assume that the node was programmed in another version of ROS, since the original programmer does not have this problem.

I get this error:

```
By not providing "Findeigen.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "eigen", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "eigen" with any of
  the following names:

    eigenConfig.cmake
    eigen-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "eigen" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "eigen_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "eigen"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

The eigen library works on my C++ projects, so I know that it is correctly installed. I just can't get it to work with ROS.
I looked around to find a solution and I added:

```
find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
find_package(eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

to the CMakeLists.txt, and

```
<build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>
<run_depend>cmake_modules</run_depend>
```

to the package.xml. However, it didn't solve the problem.
Does anybody have the same problem with eigen? What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213872/eigenconfig.cmake-not-found-(ros-indigo)/) by [Valerio](https://answers.ros.org/users/22015/valerio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you have almost everything correct.
But in `find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)`, `Eigen` should start with a capital letter.
[See the Usage document on cmake_modules](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md#usage)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-16**:
oh, and the `run_depend` for `cmake_modules` is not required.

**Comment by [soheilred](https://answers.ros.org/users/5280/soheilred/) on 2015-08-11**:
I have the same problem. I did all the steps that you have mentioned. but when I compile my code I get this:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LDLT.h:52:40: error: ‘RowMajorBit’ was not declared in this scope
Options = MatrixType::Options & ~RowMajorBit,

this is not the whole error

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-12**:
Well, please make a new question with the full error output. Also, include the `CMakeLists.txt`, the `package.xml` and, if possible, a minimal example with the error. Or the full source code, if possible (preferably in a link to a repo or a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/)).